# Creating and Using Classes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

If I create an instance of the class below and call the spawn function from my controller, the sprite will appear but I won't be able to change any of its properties.

```
class Hero: SKSpriteNode
{
    var hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero3")

    func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    {
        hero.size = size
        hero.position = position
        hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
        hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        hero.zPosition = 10
        parentNode.addChild(hero)
    }
}
```

If I get rid of the hero property and change everything to self, it works fine.

```
class Hero: SKSpriteNode
{
    func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint, size:CGSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    {
        self.size = size
        self.position = position
        self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "hero3")
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.zPosition = 10
        parentNode.addChild(self)
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is swift 101, but can someone please explain why the first version doesn't work as expected?

Comment: You say that you can't change any of your sprite's properties—could you give an example of how you're trying to change them?

Comment: Sure... ourHero.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you created a var (basically a `SpriteNode` inside the `SpriteNode`).

When you instantiate the class like `let hero = Hero(....)` you now have a SpriteNode called hero, with a property called `hero`.  You can change either.  Calling hero.size would change the base hero, and hero.hero.size would change the inside SpriteNode....this is probably not the behavior you were looking for.

The second class looks correct, if you are just trying to create a SpriteNode and modify it.  The class is a subclass of SpritNode, so it's already a SpriteNode - no need to create one inside it like the first one.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Hero class` inherits from SKSpriteNode, so it is essentially an SKSpriteNode already, which means you don't need to create a hero SKSpriteNode variable.

In your first class, when you use `hero.size = size`, you're accessing the properties of the variable *within* your class instead of *on* the class itself. Then you add the hero SKSpriteNode as a child along with all its properties, but your class SKSpriteNode, which holds the variable doesn't have set properties size or a physics body. You can think of the class as a container that's holding the variable SKSpriteNode.

In your second function, when you use `self.size = size`, you're accessing the class's properties and giving the class SKSpriteNode all the properties you need to use it in other classes.